# Calling popup from selection of JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have created a `JList` and I want to generate a popup window when the user selects one of the select components in Single Mode.

Can anyone tell me how I can do that?  And please keep in mind that I am a beginner. So in case I have some mistakes, I hope you can bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

You can [add a listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#addListSelectionListener%28javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener%29) to be notified of selection events. You'll want to create a class that implements [ListSelectionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html), then use that to do whatever you want to do when something is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example regarding your question [take a look](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9ivbwqjjrvz0pt1/EAIMdkKb_L)

Answer (score 0):

First of all; suppose that you have a JList as:

```
 list = new javax.swing.JList();

list.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "POPUP" };
public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
});
```

Since, you have to add it in your desired container so after that you have to use actionListener Suppose on a JButton.
Then suppose the user will select the model "POPUP" to want to popup a window you will give him that by using:

```
 private void jButton1MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    if(list.getSelectedIndex()==4){

            pop.show(evt.getComponent(), evt.getX(), evt.getY());

    }
}
```

where jButton is any component to be pressed for show the popup window and

```
  if(list.getSelectedIndex()==4)
```

is being used to select the desired model from the JList thats it!